# Snap GPS (lat/long) coordinates for the purposes of caching

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

Querying https://nationalmap.gov/epqs to query for elevations make them available offline. Later on folks can specify a lat-long and can get it from the offline store.

The way I'd like to do this is to snap a given coordinates to a 10ft grid (or 100ft grid or whatever). So I'd prequery all values on the grid and store them, then when the offline query comes I can snap the request lat/long to the grid and just lookup the relevant value.

The problem is that I'd like my grids to be homogenized, that is that if two grids overlapped then their points would overlap if that makes sense. So I need a standardized offset for each grid so they all line up. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I guess I could use an arbitrary point nearby and do all offsets for the grids off that?

Comment: Which coordinate system do you use? If it is just US, you can just truncate the angle (so lat and long) to your desired precision. Check the links in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Length_of_a_degree . Check on extreme point of your sector: it should be ok, but maybe Alaska (and possibly just northern part of it). or according latitude (approximation) you can use 2 to 5 different truncation ratios)